# How to Use Google Ads with my iOS App and Comply with App Tracking Transparency

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics, apptrackingtransparency

I have an iOS app that I would like to advertise using Google Ads. However, because I can't track conversions it just says "Misconfigured".

I am currently updating my app and I have create a Firebase Project and imported Firebase into my App as Google Ads suggested.

But I am now concerned about Apple's App Tracking Transparency and the 'nutrition' label. If I select the dependancy "FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport" is that enough to set up a conversion, like "First Open" to satisfy Google Ads but also enough that I don't need to ask permission from my app user to track anything.

Personally I don't really want to track or collect any data, alls I want is for my Google Ads to work so if there is another way around it that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan not to implement ATT framework, [Firebase Analytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=ios#optional_disable_apple_ad_network_attribution_registration) automatically registers your app to Apple's [SKAdNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork) to track your attribution. As per this [Google Ads doc](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10307993?hl=en), it says that SKAdnetwork works with Google Ads and Firebase, so you should be able to track your ads. Make sure you're using the latest Firebase Analytics SDK version for iOS. As the SKAdnetwork is only available on SDK version 6.29.0 and higher versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that's great. I'm not sure if it has automatically registered to SKAdNetwork, would I expect to see something in the info plist if that's the case. Also, is there any code I need to add to the app to make this work do you know - look like I might need a SKADNetwork class?

Comment: The SDK automatically calls the Apple's SKAdNetwork unless you manually disabled it on your app. You could check [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article:~:text=Use%20the%20Google%20Analytics%20for%20Firebase%20iOS%20SDK%20to%20register%20attribution%20with%20SKAdNetwork) for your reference.